# Self-flying commercial aircraft!

Tags: aircraft-design, commercial-aviation

I'm sure that all the technological advancements in various field are enabling us to create or develop stuffs which were unthinkable even few decade ago. My question is what is the current R&D stage in self flying commercial aircraft or any project in the pipeline ? Also, who is leading this concept?

Comment: We don't have the self driving bike anymore, it was only available on [April 1st](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSZPNwZex9s) .

Comment: Self-flying is not enough. There are self-flying aircraft, e.g. drones. There are self-flying airliners, e.g. on autopilot. So the question is the degree of autonomy, which cannot be total: there are tasks still requiring a human, e.g. deciding when the aircraft flies and where it goes, and it's easy to think about more tasks like that.